# Proof - Inverse of linear function is linear

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, soft-question, proof-verification, proof-writing

This is my first proof related to linear functions.
It refers to the linear-algebra-$\textit{linear}$ (not the calculus-$\textit{linear}$).
Please comment.

### Theorem

The inverse of a linear bijection is linear.

### Proof

Let $X,Y$ be vector spaces over a common field.
Let $f : X \rightarrow Y$ be a linear bijection.
We denote by $f^{-1}$ the inverse of $f$.
It remains to prove that $f^{-1}$ is linear,
i.e. both $\textit{additive}$ and $\textit{homogeneous}$.

#### Additivity

Let $y_1, y_2 \in Y$.
We prove that $$f^{-1}(y_1 + y_2) = f^{-1}(y_1) + f^{-1}(y_2).$$
\begin{equation*}
 \begin{split}
  f^{-1}(y_1) + f^{-1}(y_2)
   &= f^{-1}\Big( f\big( f^{-1}(y_1) + f^{-1}(y_2) \big) \Big) && \quad \text{by bijectivity} \\
   &= f^{-1}\Big( f\big( f^{-1}(y_1) \big) +
            f\big( f^{-1}(y_2) \big) \Big) && \quad \text{by linearity of } f \\
   &= f^{-1}\Big( y_1 + f\big( f^{-1}(y_2) \big) \Big) && \quad \text{by bijectivity} \\
   &= f^{-1}(y_1 + y_2) && \quad \text{by bijectivity}\phantom{\Big(\Big)} \\
 \end{split}
\end{equation*}

#### Homogeneity

Let $y \in Y$ and let $s$ be a scalar.
We prove that $$f^{-1}(sy) = sf^{-1}(y).$$
\begin{equation*}
 \begin{split}
  sf^{-1}(y)
   &= f^{-1}\Big( f\big( sf^{-1}(y) \big) \Big) && \quad \text{by bijectivity} \\
   &= f^{-1}\Big( sf\big( f^{-1}(y) \big) \Big) && \quad \text{by linearity of } f \\
   &= f^{-1}(sy) && \quad \text{by bijectivity}\phantom{\Big(\Big)} \\
 \end{split}
\end{equation*}

QED

Comment: Your proof is good. You can however combine the arguments to prove that $g(\alpha y+\beta z)=\alpha g(y)+\beta g(z)$ (here $g=f^{-1}$). This will make your write-up shorter.

Answer (score 3):

General principle: You can demonstrate two vectors in X are equal by showing that f maps them to the same vector in Y (since f is injective).  For example: Apply $f$ to $f^{-1}(y_1)+f^{-1}(y_2)$ and argue that the result is $y_1 + y_2$.  Do a similar calculation involving $f^{-1}(y_1+y_2)$.  You should then be able to see why the inverse of an additive injection is additive. Homogeneity can be approached the same way.  You may observe that surjectivity of $f$ is not really involved in what is going on here.

Comment: Of course surjectivity *is* involved.

Comment: Perhaps I was too elliptical? My surjectivity comment was intended to refer to the additivity & homogeneity properties holding whenever the $y$ values were part of the image of $f$.  That the image is $Y$ may be important in some context but it is not relevant to other properties at issue.

Answer (score 1):

By definition a linear map holds the following:

$i) F(a + b)= F(a) + F(b) \\ ii)F(ka)=kF(a)$ where $a \in V$, V is a vector space and $k \in K$, K is a field.

The theorem above shows that the function $f^{-1}$ preserves both vector addition and scalar multiplication.